# React.js and Material ui - handleclick function not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use react.js with material-ui. However, my event handlers do not seem to work.

For example, I tried playing around with the boilerplate material js file: (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/lists/NestedList.js )

The **handleclick** function does not work in my application (i.e. clicking on it does not collapse the list).

Th one major difference is that I used the code in a jsx file instead of js (however, changing the file to js does not solve the problem).

my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { List, ListItem, ListItemText, Collapse, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { ExpandLess, ExpandMore } from '@material-ui/icons'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary,
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
  },
});

class NestedList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: true };
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ open: !this.state.open }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List
          component="nav"
        >
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemText 
              disableTypography
              primary={<Typography type="subheadling" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Favourite</Typography>} 
            />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemText 
                disableTypography
                primary={<Typography type="subheadling" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Playlists</Typography>} 
            />
            {this.state.open ? <ExpandLess style={{ color: 'white' }} /> : <ExpandMore style={{ color: 'white' }} />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText 
                  disableTypography
                  primary={<Typography type="subheadling" style={{ color: 'white' }}>{`p1`}</Typography>} 
                />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText 
                    disableTypography
                    primary={<Typography type="subheadling" style={{ color: 'white' }}>{`p2`}</Typography>} 
                />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(NestedList);
```

**Update**
I suspect there is something wrong with the **onClick** Event since click is not listed as an event listener on the browser.

Comment: It would be better if you provide React snippet in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: @Leogoesger answered correctly below. You're using `setState` wrong

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you should try  `button={true}` instead of just `button` on your list item. Like this: `<ListItem button={true} onClick={this.handleClick}>`

Comment: Ignore that last comment. Using `button` is just fine. Works for me in a sandbox. Go the the list component and try it out here https://codesandbox.io/s/2w5z9q0zmj

Comment: @CaseyC, thanks for the reply. My NestedList.jsx is a child component of NavBar.jsx which is the child of App.jsx (so App.jsx - NavBar.jsx - NestedList.jsx). Do I need to pass the `onClick` down to the child component for it to work? Is `handleclick()` suppose to be in the parent component?

Comment: setState expects an object. instead of function.

Comment: @stackcafe123 No you don't need to pass your onClick down or anything. Leogoesger and I left working sandboxes for you. Leo's is in the comments below and is basically identical to your code. Use his sandbox exactly and see if you can get it to work. My guess is that you're getting an unrelated error that's freezing your app. Check the output in your console and in your terminal window for errors. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help. I really appreciate the help from @Leogoesger and @CaseyC. Made me realize what's working in my code and where to debug for errors.

So the reason that the event handler didn't work is because I only rendered my Material-ui files on the server side and `renderToString()` stripped out all the event handlers.

I followed the instruction here: https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/ and managed to get my App working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example of your code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k2nkj8705r

Neither of the following solutions might be what you are looking for, but here are a couple things you might want to watch out for:

Using `handleEvent = () => {}` is part of the `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`. This gives you the implicit binding so you dont have to bind it youself. Otherwise, typically you will have to write differently like the following.

```
  handleClick {
    this.setState(state => ({ open: !this.state.open }));
  };
```

Then whenever you need to to use it, you have two options. Option 1 via `bind`. You can do that in your `constructor`.

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

Or(example `onClick` in a `div`). Another approach is to create a new function for every instance, not very efficient.

```
<div onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click me</div>
```

Although not a problem, setState is like this.

```
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };
```

When calling `setState`, you just need to pass in an object.

Comment: The way they are using `handleClick` is perfectly valid here. So they don't need to bind in the constructor or bind using an arrow function in the div. You're right though that they are using `setState` wrong

Comment: hi @LeoGoesger and @CaseyC, thanks for the help.  I changed `setState` to `this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });`. However,  it still doesn't work. I suspect the there is something wrong with the `onClick` since click is not listed as one of the event listener in my browser.

Comment: @stackcafe123 I added an example using onClick event, I pretty much just copied your code and removed some unused code. https://codesandbox.io/s/k2nkj8705r

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to bind your `handleClick` on your constructor, add this line to the bottom of your constructor `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`.

I just notice that you use `handleClick = () => { ... }`, if the babel was configured properly the binding won't be needed anymore, but let's try it and let me know if it's working or not